# How to mock ethereum provider for unit testing of REST API with jest?

Tags: ethers.js, web3-providers, unittesting, mock

How to mock a ethereum provider for unit testing of REST API?

REST API has following basic structure(index.js)where provider,wallets are created using web3HttpProvider and etherjs when server is started.

Solution tried:
index.test.js

```
const web3HttpProvider= require ("web3-providers-http)
jest.mock("web3-providers-http",()=>{
return provider;});

beforeAll(async()=>{ 
console.log("test:",new web3HttpProvider(url,null));});

Error:Which results in web3HttpProvider is not a constructor.
```

Index.js

```
const web3HttpProvider=require("web3-providers-http");
const {ethers}= require ("ethers");

const app= express();
var provider=new web3HttpProvider (url,options);
var deploymentProvider= new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(provider);
Var wallet= new ethers.Wallet(privatekey, deploymentProvider);
var contractInstance= new ethers.Contract(address,abi,wallet);

app.get("/getvalue",async(req,res)=>{
var response=await instance.greeting();
res.status(200).json({response})
});

app.listen(port,()=>{console.log("server listening")});
```

Answer (score 1):

This library should help you with that https://github.com/rsksmart/mock-web3-provider

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue using `Web3Modal`. I solved it by partially mocking a class, [more info in the Jest docs page](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials). I'm sure you can apply this same concept to `web3HttpProvider`

In my `connectWallet.test.js` file I have the following:

This `const` declaration corresponds to a class named `InjectedRepository` with a `connectWallet` method:

```js
const InjectedRepository = {
   connectWallet: () => {
     return {
        account: "0x22933773a6020feb3bc10d4c8c8d47b033fa20cc",
        hasWallet: true,
        isActive: true,
        isCorrectChain: true,
        isWalletConnected: true,
        library: "Web3Provider",
        provider: "Proxy",
        selectedChain: "undefined",
        signer: "JsonRpcSigner",
      }
   }
    
}
```

Later, I use `jest.mock` to point to the actual class, and then returns the previous declared varaible instead(InjectedRepository):

```js
jest.mock("../blockchain/repositories/InjectedRepository", () => {
  return { InjectedRepository }
})
```

Hope it helps!